# jQuery - Best way to determine a child element inside list item

Tags: jquery, attributes, element

From the following HTML I need to figure out which List tag has class active and further on for the active List I need to find the relevant  value

```
    <li class="active">
    <a href="value1" class="Tab1">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="value2" class="Tab2">Create Account</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="value3" class="Tab3">Modify Account</a>
    </li>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('li.active a').attr('href')` would return 'value1'

Comment: Thanks..what happens if my any chance 2 List tags have class active...which one takes preference?

Comment: According to the jQuery documentation, the `attr` function will "[a]ccess a property on the first matched element."

Answer (score 2):

```
$("li.active a").text()
```

will retrieve the innerHTML

```
$("li.active a").attr("href")
```

will retrieve the path

and

```
$("li.active a").attr("class")
```

will retrieve the class.

**EDIT:** Updated the selectors to select the link and not the list item.

Comment: $("li.active").attr("href")

this will not return me the <a> tags href value instead it will return the <li> href value.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want, if you're wanting to see "Services":

```
$("li.active a").text();
```